# "device not accepting address X, error -32" when connecting webcam

Tags: usb, webcam

When trying to plug in a USB webcam (Logitech QuickCam Pro 3000) to my Raspberry Pi, I'm getting some wonky errors:

```
[    3.073211] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.593168] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 4, error -32
[    3.693183] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    4.223146] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 5, error -32
[    4.333124] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[    4.783152] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 6, error -32
[    4.903162] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[    5.363167] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 7, error -32
[    5.388312] usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Everything works great when I plug it into my Linux laptop:

```
[ 7730.081964] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci
[ 7730.308214] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=08b0
[ 7730.308227] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 7730.408153] pwc: Logitech QuickCam Pro 3000 USB webcam detected.
[ 7730.779493] pwc: Registered as video1.
[ 7730.779684] input: PWC snapshot button as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-3/input/input14
[ 7730.783717] usbcore: registered new interface driver Philips webcam
[ 7730.918441] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

The Pi should be fully upgraded, and is hooked up to a 2A USB charger.

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberry01 4.1.19+ #858 Tue Mar 15 15:52:03 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Also tried upgrading the kernel manually, same problem:

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberry01 4.4.31+ #922 Mon Nov 14 15:31:57 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

The port works, I tried it with a USB keyboard earlier and also swapped the camera and the WiFi dongle around. So, how can I go about getting my Pi to accept this 10+ years old camera?

Comment: In my case the problem was caused by powering my Pi by another Pi. It was resolved as soon as I connected the Pi to another power supply.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to this problem. The camera works if I disable ARM FIQ in /boot/cmdline.txt by appending:

```
dwc_otg.fiq_enable=0
```

After rebooting:

```
[    4.485155] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    4.721046] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=08b0
[    4.733564] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    9.076551] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    9.567702] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    9.952807] pwc: Logitech QuickCam Pro 3000 USB webcam detected.
[   12.340523] pwc: Registered as video0.
[   12.461754] input: PWC snapshot button as /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/input/input0
[   12.605685] usbcore: registered new interface driver Philips webcam
```