# How to deal with the error “device descriptor read/64, error -32”?

Tags: usb, power, usb-power

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 model B+ together with a Waveshare touch screen model [7inch HDMI LCD (C)](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(C)) which claims to be “low consumption,” although gives no precise amperage of the device.

Anyway, sometimes the Raspberry Pi boots correctly, but more often than not (say nine times out of ten) it shows a lot of USB-related errors in syslog, and the monitor is powered correctly, but the touch part doesn't work.

The errors look like this:

> usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 14, error -32
>   usb 1-1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device

or:

> usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
>   usb 1-1-port3: attempt power cycle

Searching through the Internet, I find a lot of resources suggesting three things.

- [Some](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=182297) claim that the fault is the power supply. I tried to power the Raspberry Pi with (1) a 2.4A charger, (2) a 3A charger, and (3) a 5V 12A power supply. While I understand that a 2.4A charger may not be ideal, the 12A PSU should be largely enough. I also tested different USB cables.
- Others suggest to put [one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57671/67792) or [all](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=159170) options among `dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_enable=0`, `dwc_otg.fiq_enable=0`, and `dwc_otg.nak_holdoff=0`. I tried to put all three, although I cannot find any relevant information about what those options are, and don't know what they really do. Anyway, I observed no difference.
- [Others](https://askubuntu.com/a/341702/229568) assert that it is “triggered when power consumption from the port is too high.” Possible, although I'm surprised that a few LEDs for screen backlighting and the touch itself is too much for Raspberry Pi (as the screen itself gets its main power rather through HDMI).
- Also, there are mentions of [other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22340730/240613), such as a wrong frequency or damaged USB device. Regarding the frequency, I did the test with another, brand new Raspberry Pi 3 B+, and the result is still the same. Damaged touch screen? Possible, but weird.
- Finally, a few resources mention `max_usb_current=1` setting in `/boot/config.txt`. I already have this setting, given that [I'm not sure if I should](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/27708/67792), after all.

So, what are my options?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @PierrePretorius: not really. The current “solution” in my case is to turn the power off and back on, until the touch screen starts working. I thought about providing the external power to the monitor, but didn't do it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this also. Resolved with a different cable.